# Database not being populated in SpringBoot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am having problem with application build from scratch using SpringBoot. I have created models and when I run application tables are being created proprely from themmmmm, but I am unable to populate tables with some default data. Here is my database configuration located in application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/open_id
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.data=classpath:data.sql

spring.jpa.show-sql=true 
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

and there is content of data.sql file (located in src/main/resources):

```
INSERT INTO user_ VALUES ('1183b214-4333-4c54-ad9b-b855aa7ecdf2', null, true, 'lomo1298@gmail.com', 'Admin', 'Admin', null, false, to_date('01-01-2100', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'admin', 'ans', 'que', 'admin');
```

If I change spring.datasource.data value to something different then I have error that values is incorrect, which probably means it wasn't able to find file. If it's like it's now in my code then everything builds fine, application starts, but user_ table is empty. Can somebody please help me figure this out? I have spent few days on this so far and I am unable to move forward.

Comment: > If it's like it's now in my code then everything builds fine, application starts, but user_ table is empty                                                                                                                                                                



It means content of file _data.sql_ is not executed. Why don't you paste same query into _schema.sql_ file under _src/main/resource_ folder and check. FYI- _schema.sql_ would be executed by spring by default during startup. If you are going with _schema.sql_ file then no need to define _spring.datasource.data_ property.

Comment: I have just tried that and still there was no result. I've renamed file to schema.sql and commented line spring.datasource.data=classpath:data.sql.

Comment: Weird, I have tried on my project and it worked. Here is a log,

2018-06-18 22:24:06.962  INFO 22892 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executing SQL script from URL [file:/my--service/target/classes/schema.sql]

Infect I can see values updated in database. 

Which version of Spring-boot are you using?

Comment: 2.0.1.RELEASE with springDataJpa 2.0.5.RELEASE

Comment: OK.. I tried today on new application with _2.0.1.RELEASE_ version. Initially it did not work. Then I have added property _spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always_ in _application.properties_ file and it started working.  

Here is a stacktrace,


2018-06-19 12:09:49.244  INFO 8496 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2018-06-19 12:09:49.249  INFO 8496 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executing SQL script from URL [file:/..:/workspace/demo/demo/target/classes/schema.sql]

Comment: Thanks mate, after I've added this line into my configuration schema.sql was executed, but also file provided in spring.datasource.data is executed.